# Servlet RequestDispatcher#include and pathInfo

Tags: java, servlets

I want to include the output of another servlet into the current response.

I can call

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/new/url").include(request, response);
```

and it does go to the right servlet, but `request.getPathInfo()`, `request.getServletPath()` and friends do not get set to the new URL (they still have the old values), so the servlet does not work.

Is that supposed to be like that? And what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's supposed to be like that (from javadoc, note that Adeel Ansari cited javadoc for `forward()` method instead of `include()`):

> The ServletResponse object has its path elements and parameters remain unchanged from the caller's.

However, included servlet can access its own path info as request attributes with the following names:

> javax.servlet.include.request_uri
>   javax.servlet.include.context_path
>   javax.servlet.include.servlet_path
>   javax.servlet.include.path_info
>   javax.servlet.include.query_string

Comment: I see. That requires the Servlet to be aware that it is being included, though (which I guess makes sense since it is not allowed to do certain things such as set a content-type).

Comment: Thanks for knowledge sharing, +1. By the way, FYI, I cited the `docs` from both. And the one I cited from `forward()` method is making complete sense because it's regarding obtaining `RequestDispatcher`. Now the use depends on what user wants, either invoke `forward()` or `include()`.

Comment: @Adeel: Sorry, didn't noticed that. Perhaps it's unclear in javadoc, but this phrase from `forward()` description actually means that path information is not changed when calling `forward()` on `RequestDispatcher` obtained from `ServletContext.getNamedDispatcher()`.